# How to display product summary by ID

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

In one of my template page called `reservation.php` I want to display a product summary.

But Woocommerce only allow me to display the entire product page with this shortcode :

```
[product_page id="99"]
```

What I want is **only** to display its summary and not everything.

Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
add_shortcode('cat_description', 'my_cat_description_shortcode'); 

function my_cat_description_shortcode($atts){ 
$a = shortcode_atts( array( 'id' => 0, ), $atts ); 
return category_description($a['id']); 
}

echo do_shortcode('[cat_description id="' . $category_id . '"]'); 
?>
```

Comment: It displays nothing , I put this function into functions.php

Comment: add_shortcode('product_data','custom_product_function'); function custom_product_function($atts) { $post_id = $atts['id']; $product = wc_get_product( $post_id ); // add data that applies to every product type $product_data = $product->post->post_content; return $product_data; }

Comment: by using shortcode: [product_data id=56],  you will get description

Comment: put this code in function.php and shortcode in any page where you want to display.

Comment: its helpful for you buddy ?